# Trying to allow a user to change their email

Tags: php, mysql

I'm just trying to allow a user to change their details, 'Username' and 'Password' I'm trying to allow a user to also update their email which then updates PHP my 'Username' and 'Password' works but I am struggling with Email. Any have an idea?

```
<?php
session_start();



$username = $_SESSION['sess_user'];

echo '<div class="search1"><h2>'.$username.'</h2></div>';


if (isset($_SESSION['sess_user']))
{
//user is logged in

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
//start changing password
//check fields

$oldpassword = md5($_POST['oldpassword']);
$newpassword = md5($_POST['newpassword']);
$email = md5($_POST['email']);


$repeatnewpassword = md5($_POST['repeatnewpassword']);

//check password against db
include('../includes/config.php');

$queryget = mysql_query("SELECT password FROM login WHERE username='$username'") or die ("change password failed");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryget);
$oldpassworddb = $row['password'];

//check passwords
if ($oldpassword==$oldpassworddb)
{
//check two new passwords
if ($newpassword==$repeatnewpassword)
{
//successs
//change password in db

$querychange = mysql_query("UPDATE login SET password='$newpassword' WHERE   username='$username'");
$querychange = mysql_query("UPDATE login SET email='$email' WHERE   email='$email'");
die("<div class='successmate'>Your password has been changed. <a href='index2.php'><br><br> Return</a></div>");
}
else 
die("<div class='results'>New password doesn't match!</div>");

}else 
die("<div class='results'>Old password doesn't match!</div>");

}
else
{

echo"
<form class='search1' action='changepassword.php' method='POST'>
<label>Old Password:</label> <input type='text' id='password' name='oldpassword'><p>
<label>New Password:</label> <input type='password' id='password' name='newpassword'><p>
<label>Repeat New Password:</label> <input type='password'  name='repeatnewpassword'><p>
<label>Email:</label> <input type='email'  name='email'><p>
<input type='submit' name='submit' class='submit' value='submit'><br><br><br>
<h2><p><a href='index2.php'>Back</a></p></h2>
</form>
";
 }

 }else 
die ("You must be logged in to change your password");


?>

<img src="../images/main.jpg">
```

Thanks!

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php). 
You are using [an **unsuitable** hashing algorithm](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) and need to [take better care](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet) of your users' passwords.

Comment: [`Don't use md5($_POST...`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5)

Comment: @Quentin Thanks for the feedback, but I will not be making this website live.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of the answers above should tell you what the problem is, however the proper way to fix it is to implement an autoincrement column or some other unique/primary column. If multiple users have the same username or you are going to update all of them.

Also, what good reason do you have to md5 the email address?

```
$email = md5($_POST['email']);
```

should be

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
```

Final Thought: You're query might be vulnerable to injection. Don't forget to [escape](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php), or even better, use [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) :)

Comment: It's impossible for it to be a same user.

Comment: If your username is the primary or unique field then you're fine, but I'm not going to assume it is.

Comment: Whoever downvoted, didn't you see the "leave a comment" notice?

Comment: Adel, I'm just having an issue why is my email being hashed in MySQL? It's not being hashed anywhere. ( I've updated my code to the one you listed above)

Comment: @Ariana I would hope so, I put that in my answer :P. If this helped you please hit the check mark by my answer. Good luck with your app.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this VERY closely:

```
$querychange = mysql_query("UPDATE login SET email='$email' WHERE   email='$email'");
```

`$email` is an md5 hash of the **NEW** email that user's entered. And since it's the new email address, presumably it won't be in the database yet, so that update will do nothing.

Comment: It did update the email but t made it hash. I am unsure of why it's doing so? I'd like the email to be normal text